# Figure out if two images have the same aspect ratio in php

Tags: php, image, aspect-ratio, image-size

If I have an image that is 2550x3300 pixels and another one that is 773x1000 pixels, how would I compare both images aspect-ratios in PHP? Both images should have the same aspect ratio since I resized it in paint.net with the "maintain aspect ratio" box clicked. But I've used various PHP attempts to figure out the aspect-ratio of each image and they come out different.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate `Aspect Ratio in PHP`

```
function gcd($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == 0 || $b == 0)
        return abs( max(abs($a), abs($b)) );

    $r = $a % $b;
    return ($r != 0) ?
        gcd($b, $r) :
        abs($b);
}

  $gcd=gcd(1024,768);

  echo "Aspect ratio = ". (2550/$gcd) . ":" . (3300/$gcd);
```

Comment: I've used this code too but the aspect ratio of both image comes out differently even though they should be the same since I resized them with maintaining aspect ratio.